# Retrieve data from JSON object uing Graph API in Android Studio

Tags: android, json, facebook-graph-api, android-activity, facebook-sdk-4.0

I want to just get the email of the user of my application. I have used Graph API.

But I am facing problems in converting the received JSON object to a string and then retrieving the data from it.

Here is a part of my code:

```
new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONObject object,
                                GraphResponse response) {
                            // Application code  
                            Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                    }
                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "email");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
```

How to get the email from the object?

Comment: First off, are you getting anything in `response` , in which case post that here? or is that not happening? If that is, then parsing is pretty simple.

Comment: Yes! I am getting correct data in response.But I dont know how to store these data in variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well in general just parse the JSON object like this

```
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(response.getRawResponse());
JSONArray data = jobj.getJSONArray("data");                             
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject indi = data.getJSONObject(i).getString("email");
.......
```